# Using remove() to ensure element is not visible in DOM or by viewing source code

Tags: javascript, shopify

I'm hoping you can help me solve a JS issue we're having.

**The Issue:**
I am removing an element when a class is present, and while this works to remove the element from the DOM via the inspector when I hit CTR-U and search for the element it is still searchable/visible.

**The blog article:**
https://www.leatherhoney.com/blogs/leather-care/diy-leather-car-interior-detailing-tips

**Background:**
The company that developed our website added (2) H1 headers to our blog articles. If the header is present, they are hiding one with CSS. This of course creates issues with multiple H1's on a page, even if it is visually hidden.

**The Fix:**
The fix is to remove the CSS property that is hiding the element and replace it with the remove() function. This would in theory remove the element entirely from the page (and from SEO crawlers) when the CSS class was present.

```
$(".hide-when-banner-enabled").remove();
```

**The Pages:**

Here's the **blog page**: https://www.leatherhoney.com/blogs/leather-care/diy-leather-car-interior-detailing-tips

Here's the **source code page** (ctrl-U) where you can still see the class *.hide-when-banner-enabled* even though it should be removed: https://www.leatherhoney.com/blogs/leather-care/diy-leather-car-interior-detailing-tips

Can anyone explain to me why this is still visible and if there is a better way to go about removing this duplicate H1 tag when a class is present so SEO is not affected by duplicate tags?

Thank you!

Comment: The "view source" thing shows the page as it existed when the browser first loaded it.

Comment: Also, there's nothing structurally wrong with having 2 or more `<h1>` tags in a document.

Comment: I personally have no issue with multiple <h1> tags, we have a company that created a list of items they want to be changed with their theme and this is one of the items. Do you know if using remove() has any effect on this element in search? Or to ensure it's not loading up 2 h1s?

Comment: It depends on the search engine, I'd guess.

Comment: The goal is to ultimately make this -duplicate- h1 tag not visible to any search engine as we're adding a new h1 to the page if a hero element is present (in the hero itself) and removing the other in-page H1 to avoid duplicate H1 tags.

Comment: You need to remove it from the source code the backend sends. It isn't really something you should try tackling with JavaScript. At the point JS runs, it is too late.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser receives the HTML document, converts it into a DOM, and runs the JS which modifies the DOM.

The source code is unchanged. It's the source code, not a reflection of the current state.

You wouldn't want web browsers to be able to rewrite the code on your server: That would lead to your homepage being vandalised with new spam 30 times a second.

If you want to change the HTML that the server sends to the browser (or sends to the search engine indexing bot) then you need to fix it **on the server**.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, that makes sense. Is there a better way to handle removing an element so it's not passed to search engines if the element should not exist on the page due to "x" conditions (in this case, a header is present with another h1)?

Comment: Generally, the best approach is to go back to the logic that generates the headings in the first place rather than trying to undo its mistakes.

Comment: Assign a different H1 class to certain divs or spans, do not use global H1. Like

 .blog h1 { whatever here} 

So your can remove the element with the H1. this wont affect other H1 elements, thats if I am reading your problem correctly.

Comment: @Jules the `<h1>` is removed successfully from the DOM. The problem is with the contents of "view source".

Comment: You can hide it or make is not visible and it will still be in your source and seen by search engines

Comment: I went through the liquid logic and assigned a few conditions for the H1 elements based on the page handle and removed the CSS and JS code. It's working splendidly now. Thank you all for the excellent information and assistance!